# Issues with shiny app; Blank output; No error message

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I've been trying to create a simple shiny app. The data I'm using is a dataframe of the daily amount of flights and passengers of an airport in .xlsx, with a date column in yyyy-mm-dd format as well as a column for each the number of the day, the month and the year. I want to be able to select a date range and to receive a corresponding plot, with x=date (the input date range) and y=flights.

Here is the head():

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  date                passengers flights pas_per_flight month day   year 
  <dttm>                   <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00      75505     563           134. 1     1     2019 
2 2019-01-02 00:00:00      92393     659           140. 1     2     2019 
3 2019-01-03 00:00:00      81189     627           129. 1     3     2019 
4 2019-01-04 00:00:00      83156     658           126. 1     4     2019 
5 2019-01-05 00:00:00      78043     560           139. 1     5     2019 
6 2019-01-06 00:00:00      87890     655           134. 1     6     2019
```

Here is the dput(head())

```
    structure(list(date = structure(c(1546300800, 1546387200, 1546473600, 
1546560000, 1546646400, 1546732800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), passengers = c(75505, 92393, 81189, 83156, 78043, 
87890), flights = c(563, 659, 627, 658, 560, 655), pas_per_flight = c(134.11190053286, 
140.201820940819, 129.488038277512, 126.376899696049, 139.3625, 
134.18320610687), month = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), day = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), year = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I came up with, but I unfortunately have no error message to report. The app runs, the daterange selector is there and working, but there is no plot being put out. The "center" of the app just stays blank.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

zhairport<-read_xlsx("airport.xlsx")

  
ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
          mainPanel(plotOutput("date")),
            sidebarPanel(
              dateRangeInput("date", "Choose timeframe", start="2019-01-01", end="2020-12-31",
                              min="2019-01-01",max="2020-12-31"),
                    )),
    
                )
  
  server<-function(input, output, session){
    subdata<-reactive({
      zhairport %>%
        filter(
          as.Date(date) >= as.Date(input$date[1]),
          as.Date(date) <= as.Date(input$date[2]),
          )
                      })
    output$plot<-renderPlot({
      ggplot(subdata(), 
             aes(x=date, y=flights)
             +geom_line(aes(x=date,y=flights)))
                          })
                                          }
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Apologies for the horrible formatting and the probably very bad code, it's my first app.

TIA for any answers!

Comment: where in the app do you load `zhairport`  (or is it just a typo ;-)  )??

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I edited out the "zh-" by mistake in the question. It's supposed to be loaded with the first read_xlsx command. Will fix. Unfortunately that's not the solution. Thanks for the heads-up. I hope the actual solution is just as "dumb" and simple :)

Comment: i see. plesae edit the results from `dput(head(zhairport))` into your question..

Comment: I have added the results in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the corrected code

```
zhairport <-structure(list(date = structure(c(1546300800, 1546387200, 1546473600, 
                                  1546560000, 1546646400, 1546732800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), passengers = c(75505, 92393, 81189, 83156, 78043,87890), flights = c(563, 659, 627, 658, 560, 655), pas_per_flight = c(134.11190053286,140.201820940819, 129.488038277512, 126.376899696049, 139.3625,134.18320610687), month = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), day = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), year = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019","2019", "2019")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)




ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")),
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("date", "Choose timeframe", start="2019-01-01", end="2020-12-31",
                     min="2019-01-01",max="2020-12-31"),
    )),
  
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
  subdata<-reactive({
    zhairport %>%
      filter(
        as.Date(date) >= as.Date(input$date[1]),
        as.Date(date) <= as.Date(input$date[2]),
      )
  })
  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    data = subdata()
    ggplot(data, 
           aes(x=date, y=flights)) +geom_line(aes(x=date,y=flights))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```